# How do I cite MIT licensed software in a research publication?

Tags: mit, attribution

I have found code provided on GitHub under an MIT license. I have modified the code to be useful for my application. In order to give proper credit to the original author/developer, how can I provide the citation in a technical paper?

Comment: If you’re at a university, it’d be best to ask your professor/research advisor.

Comment: The license imposes no special requirements regarding citations. Unless the authors have given any preferred form of citation, just cite the website (e.g. the GitHub page) of the software.

Answer (score 5):

[Zenodo](https://zenodo.org/) could be your best bet. You can create a citation with DOI using Zenodo.

Some people prefer to cite a software using `misc` tag in bibtex.

`@Misc{Software_abc2018,
  title         = {{Software/Tool name}},
  howpublished  = {\url{http://www.software_url.com/}},
  year          = {2018},
  note          = {[Online; accessed 8-Dec-2018]},
  key           = {software_abc},
}`